# Firefox windows in not opening in selenium python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(80)
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

Where is the catch and why it is not opening?

Comment: Where did instantiate the driver variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `implicit_wait` before the `driver.get`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

**Regarding your question in comments:**

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


executable_path = "path_to_webdriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: no in chrome no extension are loading up so i need t stick to firefox

Comment: @Rakeshmoorthy I was confused as one of your tags is google-chrome, edited my answer

Comment: got error os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7fe7dda67910>> ignored

Comment: @Rakeshmoorthy You can read about your error in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: omri_saadon do u know how to load extension with chrome when using selenium(im on ubuntu)?

Comment: @Rakeshmoorthy this is pretty long, so i've added this to my answer

Comment: if i give my path here chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension') it is not working

Comment: may be i will use wrong path do u know how to find path

Comment: I use this path for now .config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/nofbmmlgcejohbjpbilfpiggemkakkig